# Slitting paper rolls into small rolls with minimum waste

Tags: excel, math, combinations, permutation

I have a big paper roll with different widths (length not important).
I would like to find the best combination of small rolls that can be slit out from the main roll with minimum waste, it can be any combination. Can anyone help me to find out an automated solution for this in excel or in any other program?
Thanks.[image]

Edit:

I have tried this manually but there are a lot more combinations possible but out of these 3 trials the highlighted one is the minimum waste. Screenshot attached. I am thinking of an automated way for this.[image]

Comment: What is best? Is one particular roll more valuable? is mass better? There are multiple solutions mathematically that are all valid, how do you choose? Once you prioritise, then use the Solver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How calculate minimal waste when tailoring tubes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262263/how-calculate-minimal-waste-when-tailoring-tubes)

Comment: Are you looking at the specified three lengths only or there can be more in the supply column?

Comment: Easily solved with the [`Solver`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) addin (a std part of Excel).

Comment: In general, this problem is called the stock cutting problem. A web search for that term should find some resources.